# Opening source file by double clicking output line in Rhapsody

Tags: java, rhapsody

I was assigned to integrate a 3rd party tool into Rhapsody using Java API and one of the requirements is to show the output of the tool in Output Window. Moreover users should be able to navigate to the related source file-line by double clicking the respective line in Output Window.

Following method works OK for writing to output :

```
IRPApplication.writeToOutputWindow(java.lang.String title, java.lang.String outputStr)
```

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21649496

But I've no idea how to detect the double click on output lines and open the text editor with the related problematic line highlighted.

Is it even possible ? [Same question](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014637069&ps=25) has been asked in Rhapsody forums but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wondered how "make" was able to output something that navigates to related source file by double clicking and decided to imitate its output format. And voila ! If you print a string in the following format, Rhapsody does the trick automagically for you. No need for neither double click handler nor file opener code.

```
C:\SomeSourceFile.c:177: Some error
```